# List.Add Accidentally Adding Same Thing Multiple Times in Java

Tags: java, list, file, arraylist

I'm a complete Java novice just starting to learn about collections.  I'm attempting to write a program that can take a text file and create a list of objects from the contents of that file.  Specifically, I have a class Students in which each student has a first name, last name, and a graduation year.  The text file I'm using is of this format:

Tom Blue 2007
Richard Green 1996
Robert Black 2003
Beth White 2005

except with new lines between each student.  The problem I'm getting is when I go to create my list, it appears to create a list with multiple instances of whatever the last student is in my list.  For example, if I used a file with the four students above, my program creates a list with 4 copies of Beth White 2005.  I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here... I don't think it's a problem with my Scanner, and I'm certain it's not a problem with my print method because I've used the default print method and the same results happen.  Here's my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StudentList
{
private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file containing the students.");
    String fileName = keyInput.next();

    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>(openAndReadFile(fileName));
    printList(studentList);
}

private static List<Student> openAndReadFile(String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        input = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName));
    }
    catch (IOException ioException)
    {
        System.err.println("Error opening file.  Terminating.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

    try
    {
        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            studentList.add(new Student(input.next(), input.next(), input.nextInt()));
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException ee)
    {
        System.err.println("File improperly formed.  Terminating.");
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException se)
    {
        System.err.println("Error reading from file.  Terminating.");
    }

    if (input != null)
        input.close();

    return studentList;
}

private static void printList(List<Student> list)
{
    for (Student student : list)
        System.out.printf("%s%n", student);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the class `Student` use `static` fields by any chance?

Using `static` fields will cause just a single possible value to be assigned per field for all instances of the class, namely the last one assigned. If this is the case remove the `static` keyword so that the class fields correspond to each instance of `Student`

Comment: Not written in the form of an answer, but this must be it.

Comment: This was exactly the issue.  Thank you.  I still have yet to educate myself on the true meaning of 'static', but I appreciate the little description.